# Pass signals to program under debugger?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, signals

I have a console program that is being debugged under Eclipse. Eclipse provides a Console Panel, but it does not appear to provide a terminal.

The program has a few signal handlers installed, including `SIGHUP`, `SIGINT` and `SIGTRAP`. When I try and send a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to the program, the signal `SIGINT` never makes it to the debugee.

To date, I've had to open a separate terminal, do a `ps`, and then send the signal with `kill` (for example, `kill -s SIGINT <pid>`). But that's seems like overkill (not to mention a lot of extra work) since all I should need is a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on a foreground window or terminal.

How does one send signals to a program under the debugger?

Comment: Read [gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/) documentation. It is the debugger used by Eclipse.

Comment: Basille - Why did you even bother with that comment? Its pretty much useless unless I'm missing insight into its brilliance.